# How does IE8 and below handle media queries

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I am wondering how IE8 and below react to media queries in CSS.

I'm not looking for a solution for IE8 to render them. I'm just wondering if IE will just ignore them, or if IE will try to parse them.

Background story: we are building a responsive site, but since IE8 and below is rarely to be used on a smaller screen device, we hope IE just ignores media queries. This way IE8 (and below) users always see the "regular sized" version of the site, which is fine.

Comment: The answer to so many questions related to web standard support is "it depends".  Good luck: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/10/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/

Comment: You should really choose an answer, as your question has been sufficiently answered.

Answer (score 3):

In short, you're exactly right.

IE8 does not support media queries, and will not parse any CSS contained within them.

Therefore, if you want to support IE8 in a responsive site, you should make sure that your default CSS which you want IE8 to use is outside of any media queries.

So the short answer is that what you said in the question is pretty much exactly right.

There are other considerations of course: IE8 isn't the only browser not to know about media queries; some older Android devices and other old phones may also not support them. If you need to support those devices, you may need to consider how to handle it. Fortunately there really aren't that many people browsing the web using those devices, so you can generally ignore them unless you have a specific need.

You also have the option of using a polyfill script like [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), which adds support for media queries to older browsers like IE8. Note that this is a javascript library, so it will only run after the page has loaded, so there may be some delay and screen redrawing involved, which isn't pretty, but it is being used by a lot of sites and with good results, so you may want to consider it.

Answer (score -1):

i.e 8 does not support media queries, but these poly fills which makes media queries support to i.e 8 and i.e 7. In fact its a good option to use else you need to show  "regular sized" version of the site? its possible through some hacks i.e conditional comments of css link file and the way you write css code for i.e older browsers, try to override the styles with high css specificity.

note: if you are using html5 add another polyfill **Html5shiv** hosted by google.

use html5 and media queries like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">            </script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Check for polyfills respondjs --- http://responsejs.com/  and css3 media queries --

https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

In order to use "regular sized" version.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

learn some specs and tips,tricks log on http://www.pointmycode.com/